# PHP loop new tr after every 3 loops

Tags: php

I have a table with a PHP loop. I want it to create a new row after every 3 loops. I've got the following code. However, seems to not be working correctly. The first new row gets created after the 4th loop and every loop after that works fine. And also it seems to create a blank  at the end. Any ideas how I can get this to work?

```
<table cellpadding="20">
<tr>
    <?php
    $counter=0;
    foreach ($links as $key){

        echo '<td align="center">'.$links[$key].'</td>';
        echo "\n";

        if ($counter % 3 == 0 && $counter !== 0) {
            echo '</tr><tr>';
        }      

        $counter++;

    }
    ?>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Start $counter with 1 instead of 0

Comment: To fix the first one after 3rd and not 4th, change `$counter=0;` to `$counter=1`

Comment: This is really something you can figure out if you go through it with pen and paper… `$counter % 3 == 0` will be true when `$counter` is `3`, which will be on the *forth* iteration, and you're outputting the row terminator *after* already having output the content on said 4th iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `$counter++;` before `if` or set `$counter=1;` before `for`

Comment: didn't realise setting counter to 1 will solve the issue. works great now. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
foreach(array_chunk($links, 3) as $linkGroup) { ?>
   <tr>
       <?php
           foreach($linkGroup as $link) { ?>
              <td><?= $link['key'] ?></td>           
     <?php }
       ?>
   </tr>
<?php }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try doing it like this:

```
<?php
$counter=0;
foreach ($links as $key){

    echo '<td align="center">'.$links[$key].'</td>';
    echo "\n";

    }      
    if ($counter >= 3){
        echo '</tr><tr>';   
        $counter=0;     
    }
    $counter++;
}
?>
```